# open port for ec2 for FTP services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

I am running an instance of ec2, I want to open open FTP port

I had open port in security group 
 [image: [http://imgur.com/9rjjRl4|http://imgur.com/9rjjRl4]]

but I run   `netstat -anlt | grep LISTEN`
and I try iptables, seem like not working as well

`` [ec2-user@ip-20-0-1-35 ~]$ sudo iptables -L
iptables v1.4.18: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?) ``

I check the iptables status there is not running.

[image]

I also tested with this website, the port also not open.
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

How do I open port for 20-21 and 1024 - 1048?

Totally out of idea.

Comment: 1024-1048 may not be enough range.  It might work if the ftp server software is set up like that but maybe not.  See http://www.mdjnet.dk/ftp.html

Comment: the problem is port 20, 1024-1048 also not open in the netstat list. I am able to connect for the FTP, but stuck at the Status: Retrieving directory listing...

Comment: If you read the doc listed above port 21 is used for commands in both directions.  This works for you.  For setting up a data connection the remote client can request a connection to an high range port on the server.  So all of these ports need to be open.  If the remote client requests a high port that is not in your range 1024-1048, say (for example) port 1234 then the security group rules will block it and it will not reach the EC2 at all and will not show in output from netstat

Comment: are you running your FTP client in passive mode? 
If you dont, your client side, needs to accept back connection from server to whatever the port your pc is running. 
It is not possible these days as you would be behind NAT most of the time.

Comment: @Greyeye, I am running Filezilla FTP client, I set as passive mode still stuck at the Status: Retrieving directory listing..., The last thing I did is restart the instance then I able to connect, but according some of them said add aws security group do not need to restart, but once I restart it WORKS!